# Regex matching on to extract multi-line text regions (C#)

Tags: c#, regex, multiline, regex-lookarounds

I'm looking to capture text regions in a large text block, created in the following format:

```
...
[region:region-name]
multi line
text block
[/region]
...
[region:another-region-name]
more
multi-line text
[/region]
```

I have this almost worked out with

```
\[region:(?'link'.*)\](?'text'(.|[\r\n])*)\[/region\]
```

This works if I only had one region in the entire text. But, when there are multiple, this gives me just one block with every other 'region' included in the 'text' of that one.
I have a feeling that this is to be solved using a negative look ahead, but being a non-pro with regex, I don't know how to modify the above to do it right.
Can someone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this without lookahead:

```
\[region:(?'link'.*)\](?'text'(?s).*?)\[/region\]
```

The additional `?` makes the `*` quantifier lazy, so it will match as few characters as possible. And the `(?s)` allows the dot to match newlines after this position, so you don't have to use the `(.|[\r\n])` construction (an alternative would be `[\s\S]`).

Comment: Thanks! This worked great. Also thank you for cleaning up my regex :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a negative lookahead, just need to change `(?'text'(.|[\r\n])*)` to be "non-greedy", so that it will match the first instance of `[/region]` rather than the last. You can do this by adding `?` after `*`, so the resulting pattern would be:

```
\[region:(?'link'.*)\](?'text'(.|[\r\n])*?)\[/region\]
```

Comment: Thanks! I used Tim's suggestion above and didn't try this. But, it looks like this would have worked as well.